# What sources are there for the meaning of Yom HaMeyuchos (2nd Sivan)?

Tags: calendar, kabbalat-hatorah

[Ohr Sameach](http://ohr.edu/991) gives the chronology according to Rashi of the giving of the Torah.

> Early the following morning, the 2nd of Sivan, Moshe goes up Mt.
>   Sinai for the first time. He is instructed to offer the Jews the
>   opportunity of accepting the Torah, and of becoming a holy people.
>   (19:3-6). 
>   That same day Moshe descends and assembles the elders and
>   passes on the message. The entire people respond in unison that
>   whatever HaShem says, they will do. (19:7-8).

[Beis Tefillah Yonah Avraham](http://www.btya.org/?p=1116) points out that this day

> is traditionally known as Yom HaMeyuchos (loosely–the special day).
>   Aruch haShulchan explains why: This is the day that Moshe Rabbeinu
>   told B’nei Yisrael that they must sanctify themselves in preparation
>   for mattan Torah.

I always thought that it had this name because we became a
ממלכת כהנים וגוי קדש
and that is the yichus, distinguished lineage that we have.

What sources are there for the meaning of Yom HaMeyuchos?

Comment: זה יום המיוחס is gematria of לא נופל because there isn't Tachanun. Isn't that the original source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Because it stands between the two holy days of Rosh Chodesh Sivan and the Shloshes Yemei Hagbala (similar to [Taanis 18a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=18): "Since it was between two festivals, they made it a festival itself. See also [Sanhedrin 104a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=104). - [Ta'amey Haminhagim (610)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=266). [Nitey Gavriel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46443&pgnum=55) brings it in the name of Shu"t Haelef Lecha Shlomo (331)
- Since on that day Hashem said to us "ואתם תהיה לי ממלכת כהנים וגוי קדוש" and we thus became מיוחסין. - Likutey Maharich. [Ta'amey Haminhagim (611)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=266) in the name of Sha'ar Bas Rabim
- Because Moshe told the Jewish people on that day to sanctify themselves in preperation of Matan Torah. ([Aruch Hashulchan 494:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A6.D7.93_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96))
- Because Yom Kippur will always fall on the same day of the week as Beis Sivan ([Aruch Hashulchan there](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A6.D7.93_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96))
- The reason the Jewish people recieved the Torah was because of our יחוס, as the Yalkut says: When the Jews recieved the Torah, the nations of the world were jealous and protested, "How are these people more fit than the other nations?" Hashem replied to them: "Bring me your books of lineage.." - [Ta'amey Haminhagim (612)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=266) in name of Ezor Eliyahu Parshas Bamidar

Comment: Note the original Shloshes Yemei Hagbala began on 4 Sivan. So there were really two days in between.